# I have to post url twice before website preview image shows in Facebook post

Tags: facebook, metadata

When I post a link to facebook of one of my sites, it does not insert the preview image until I reload the page and post it for the second time, sometimes it takes a few reloads.  It's a very strange phenomenon and I would love to know what I am doing wrong.

I am using the meta property "og:image" but even without it, it does the same.

Try with this url: https://www.berkshirefinearts.com/11-22-2018_a-broadway-holiday.htm to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` tags if you want new URLs to show the `og:image` immediately:

> Specify height and width for your image to ensure that the image loads properly the first time it's shared.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#media